# Migration from ArcFM to Vanilla ESRI

Tags: arcgis-desktop, migration, arcfm

What would be the steps or process to migrate data from an ArcFM system to a vanilla installation of ESRI ArcGis?
We tried loading the SDE data into an ArcGIS installation without ArcFM and received an unable to create object class extension error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to un-ArcFM-ize the data by converting the data to be Esri objects and not arcFM objects. This is done in Arc catalog with the ArcFM extension installed and using the ArcFM object converter tool. 
[ArcFM Help for the Object Converter](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/ArcCatalogTools/ArcFM_Solution_Object_Converter.html)

I find that this is best done by the system exporting the data as it is a hassle if you don't already have ArcFM installed and an arcFM geodatabase. Schneider does provide  a free ArcFM object reader if you just need to view the data.